# How it made Cloud9 IDE? I would like to know

Tags: cloud9-ide

I would like to know, How it's really made cloud9 IDE?, is programmed in C or Assembler language?

If anyone knows anything, tell me!
Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: Sorry about that! I know

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 is built using Javascript + NodeJS

Comment: the core of cloud9 is built with JS and NodeJS??